# Regex for matching HashTags in any language

Tags: javascript, regex, multilingual, hashtag

I have a field in my application where users can enter a hashtag.
I want to validate their entry and make sure they enter what would be a proper HashTag.
It can be in any **language** and it should **NOT** precede with the # sign.
I am writing in JavaScript.

So the following are GOOD examples:

- Abcde45454_fgfgfg (good because: only letters, numbers and _)
- 2014_is-the-year (good because: only letters, numbers, _ and -)
- בר_רפאלי (good because: only letters and _)
- арбуз (good because: only letters)

And the following are BAD examples:

- Dan Brown (Bad because has a space)
- OMG!!!!! (Bad because has !)
- בר רפ@לי (Bad because has @ and a space)

We had a regex that matched only a-zA-Z0-9, we needed to add language support so we changed it to ignore white spaces and forgot to ignore special characters, so here I am.

Some other StackOverflow examples I saw but didn't work for me:

1. [Other languges don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927479/regular-expression-for-hashtag-text-with-multi-language-support)
2. [Again, English only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

[edit]

- Added explanation why bad is bad and good is good
- I don't want a preceding # character, but if I would to add a # in the beginning, it should be a valid hashtag

  - Basically I don't want to allow any special characters like !@#$%^&*()=+./,[{]};:'"?><

Comment: Your bad example doesn't contain `#` anyway. So exactly what are your forbidden characters?

Comment: Edited my question to add explanation and some more info.
Thanks!

Comment: So leading `#` is allowed, although you don't prefer, while `#` in other places are forbidden, is that?

Comment: No, I don't want to allow # in the text anywhere, I want it to be a valid hashtag phrase in multilanguage.

Comment: JavaScript regexes have no support for Unicode character classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your disallowed characters list is thorough (`!@#$%^&*()=+./,[{]};:'"?><`), then the regex is:

```
^#?[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+./,\[{\]};:'"?><]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG5iL2/1)

This allows an optional leading `#` sign: `#?`. It disallows the special characters using a negative character class. I just added `\s` to the list (spaces), and also I escaped `[` and `]`.

Unfortunately, you can't use constructs like `\p{P}` (Unicode punctuation) in JavaScript's regexes, so you basically have to blacklist characters or take a different approach if the regex solution isn't good enough for your needs.

Comment: Since the OP is matching against characters outside the (extended) ASCII set, your suggestion will match many special characters (granted, ill defined by the OP) outside of this set.

Comment: @Bart of course, I'm warning about this in the last paragraph. The only JS regex solution I could think of would require adding Unicode ranges (like `[\u2000-\u206F]`). This is left as an exercise for the OP ;)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you guys mean here.
@Lucas your answer does indeed suit me very much.
If there is a less ugly way of doing it (while still applying all my needs) I would be happy to hear it!

Thanks for the effort

Comment: @PoOoZaQ What we mean is that there is a *more* ugly way to do it, because this answer doesn't take into account every character that should be disallowed... For instance, `¶¿§‼` is a valid hashtag. But taking it into account would be a pain since you would have to add more characters to the blacklist: For instance this regex: `^#?[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+./,\[{\]};:'"?><\u2000-\u206F]+$` would make my previous `¶¿§‼` example not match. Without constructs like `\p{P}` in JS you'd have to add all the Unicode ranges to blacklist to the character class.

Comment: Note: `\p{L}` and all the character properties are available in XRegExp.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why this question does not get more votes. Hashtag detection for multiple languages is a problem. The only working option I could find is posted by Lucas above (all other ones do not work so well).

It needs a modification though:

```
#[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+.\/,\[{\]};:'"?><]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QTtUEO/1)

this detects all the hashtags, not only in the beginning of the string, fixes an unescaped character, and removes the unnecessary `$` in the end.

Comment: This incorrectly accepts `#123`. None of the major social networks appear to permit number-only hashtags.

Comment: @ceejayoz Instagram supports tag from numbers only

Answer (score 0):

First if we exclude all symbol it will not a handy solution. Because symbol depends on keyboard layout and there are hundreds of math symbols and so on. So use this..

**[\p{sc=Bengali}|\p{L}_\p{N}]+**

**1.** If you think if language need extra care include like \p{sc=Bengali}|\p{sc=Spanish} etc. Suppose bangla has surrogate alphabet like া, ে ৌ etc so codepoint need to recognize Bangla separately first by \p{sc=Bengali}

**2.** Than use \p{L} that matches anything that is a Unicode letter a-z and letters like é,ü,ğ,i,ç too or normal any alphabet without complex...matches a single code point in the category "letter"

**3.** _ underscore allowed

**4.** \p{N} matches any kind of numeric character in any script. (\d matches only a digit (equal to [0-9]) but for allowed Unicode digit \p{N} only option, because its works with any digit codepoint)

Answer (score 0):

```
/#[\p{L}\p{N}_]+/gu
```

This works for me, and addresses many of the concerns mentioned in comments.